# Tab selection problem in JSF icefaces

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

I have one tab set as below ,in which i want select dynamic tab using binding in java.

```
<ice:panelTabSet var="currentTab" partialSubmit="true"  selectedIndex="#{viewBatchBean.tabSelectedIndex}"
            value="#{viewBatchBean.batch.batchConfigurationTabList}"
            tabChangeListener="#{viewBatchBean.showDefaultValueForTab}"
            binding="#{viewBatchBean.panelTabSetRef}">
```

here i set tab index as below..

```
  panelTabSetRef.setSelectedIndex(0);
```

it set tab as per given index but doesn't set focus on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populating the panelTabSetRef.

```
//---

for(SomeObject tabConfig : batchConfigurationTabList){
   PanelTab panelTab = new PanelTab();
   // Setting appropriate values in panelTab
   panelTabSetRef.getChildren().add(panelTab);
}

//---
```

Fetching the PanelTab component from PanelTabSet & processing it accordingly.

```
List<UIComponent> panelTabs= panelTabSetRef.getChildren();

// Selecting tab to set focus

PanelTab focusTab = (PanelTab) panelTabs.get(tabSelectedIndex);
String tabId = focusTab.getId();

//---
```

Focus can be set on the selected tab as below using Java Script.

```
JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "someJSMethodToSetFocus('someForm:"+tabId+"');");
```

Index out of bound exception is raised because the panel has not been populated & fetching children from it. Giving value directly as 
`<ice:panelTabSet value="#{viewBatchBean.batch.batchConfigurationTabList}"/>` 
populates when the the page is rendered accordingly. So manually populating the panelTabSetRef.

In newer IceFaces version, tabIndex attribute has been added to panelTabSet.

Comment: solution that u given is good but when i use getChildren() method, it gives me size = 1 when in my UI it is 6...so it gives me error as index out of bound..

Comment: In my code it set focus on tab dynamically but do not refresh that tab..once i click on that tab then only it refreshing..code is too much long, so i can't post it :)